# C# Parse String into DateTime with Specific TimeZone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I've been struggling with this for a bit so I'll punt to SO.

I have an app where I need to parse strings into datetimes.  The strings look like this:

```
"201503131557"
```

(they will always be this format "yyyyMMddHHmm") and always be in Central Standard Time (or Central Daylight Time depending on the date)even though they don't specify it.

When I parse them I understand that it parses them into local time.  I'm running on Azure PaaS and don't want to change it to run in CST just to support this operation.

How do i write code that works both locally and in Azure PaaS that will correctly  parse these dates into DateTimes setting their timezone to CST?

Here is a quick unit test I wrote to prove Matt Johnson's answer.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DateTests()
    {
        var unSpecDt = DateTime.ParseExact("201503131557", "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");


        var utcDt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(unSpecDt, tz);

        var offset = tz.GetUtcOffset(unSpecDt);
        var dto =new DateTimeOffset(unSpecDt, offset);


        var cstDt = dto.DateTime;

        Assert.IsTrue(cstDt.Hour - utcDt.Hour == offset.Hours);
    }
```

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I don't understand the question.  These strings will always be CST / CDT date times.  I need to parse them into DateTimes in an app that I need to run locally on my laptop (which runs in CST / CDT) but also in Azure PaaS.

Comment: I think the question is clear, but I understand why some might downvote it, as it doesn't show research effort.  If you wanted to improve the question, you could edit it to show what you tried and explain what you wanted to do with the result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To parse the string, since you have only the date and time, and you know the specific format the strings will be in, do this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("201503131557", "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The resulting value will have its `Kind` property set to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` (not local time, as you thought).  That is to be expected, as you provided no information regarding how this timestamp is related to UTC or local time.

You said the value represents time in Central Standard Time.  You'll need a `TimeZoneInfo` object that understands that time zone.

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
```

Note that this identifier represents the Central Time observed in the USA, including both CST or CDT depending on which is in effect for the given value (despite the word "Standard" in its name).  Also note that it valid on Windows operating systems only.  If you wanted to use .NET Core on some other OS, then you'd need to pass the IANA identifier `"America/Chicago"` instead (or use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library to use either identifier on any platform).

The next step is to figure out what you want to *do* with this value.  You might do a few different things with it:

- If you want to convert it to the equivalent UTC value, represented as a `DateTime`, then you can do this:

  ```
  DateTime utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, tz);
  ```
- If you want a `DateTimeOffset` representation which holds the input you gave and the offset from UTC as it related to US Central Time, then you can do this:

  ```
  TimeSpan offset = tz.GetUtcOffset(dt);
  DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);
  ```

  Keep in mind that it's possible for the input time is invalid or ambiguous if it falls near a DST transition.  The `GetUtcOffset` method will return the *standard* offset in such cases.  If you want different behavior, you have more code to write (out of scope for this post).
- There are other things you might do, all of which are provided by the [`TimeZoneInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo) class.

Note that "Azure PaaS" might refer to a few different things, and while there is a setting called `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` in Azure App Service - I don't recommend you lean on it.  Consider it a last resort to be used only when you *can't* control the code.  In most cases, it is better off writing your code to never depend on the time zone setting of the system it runs on.  That means never calling `DateTime.Now`, or `TimeZoneInfo.Local`, `DateTime.ToLocalTime`, or even `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` (since it converts *from* the local time zone), etc.  Instead, rely upon methods that work explicitly with either UTC or a specific time zone or offset.  Then you will never need to care about where your app is hosted.

Lastly, understand that neither the `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` types have any capability of understanding that a value is tied to a specific time zone.  For that, you'd need to either write your own class, or look to the [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) library whose `ZonedDateTime` class provides such functionality.

Comment: wow thanks! this is exactly the info I needed.  Thanks for clearing up my misconceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

[DateTime.ParseExact(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
public static DateTime ParseExact (string s, string format, IFormatProvider provider);
```

This datetime do not have any metadata about timezone. You can convert to UTC and then you will be sure that you are able to convert to all timezones.

Comment: If I use this locally (on a machine that is CST) vs running in Azure PaaS (where my understanding is the local timezone is UTC) won't I get different dates?

Comment: if you know that date what you want parse is correct in UTC you have to parse it as UTC and then it will be ok .. I do not know about efficient way but for example, you can parse it to any date time then you will create new date time where you will set ticks from firstly parsed date time and set `DateTimeKind` to `UtcKind`..... or another way is to use nuget package [noda time](https://nodatime.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTime.TryParseExact(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8) method with `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` to avoid conversion.

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact("201503131557", "yyyyMMddHHmm", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out dt);
```

If you need to convert you will need to go to UTC then use the conversion methods of `TimeZoneInfo` with `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time")`.